# Chrome freezes on startup and when opening the Downloads tab

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, freeze

Chrome is always unresponsive on startup for about 3 seconds. Similarly it often becomes unresponsive and freezes when going to `Downloads` (Here the tab doesn't open correctly initially having the wrong size. It is also unresponsive for longer, like 10 seconds.)

I have tried installing all OS updates. I have tried turning of hardware acceleration. I have tried switching Nvidia drivers from 470 to 535, nothing has helped.

---

Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Ti, Version 119.0.6045.105 (Official Build) (64-bit).

---

It hangs the same way when opening chrome with

```
google-chrome --disable-gpu
```

It shows the following errors in that case:

```
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0

Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Warning: disabling flag --expose_wasm due to conflicting flags
Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file: No such file: (null)
Warning: loader_scanned_icd_add: Driver /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_radeon.so supports Vulkan 1.2, but only supports loader interface version 4. Interface version 5 or newer required to support this version of Vulkan (Policy #LDP_DRIVER_7)
Warning: loader_scanned_icd_add: Could not get 'vkCreateInstance' via 'vk_icdGetInstanceProcAddr' for ICD libGLX_nvidia.so.0
Warning: loader_scanned_icd_add: Driver /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_lvp.so supports Vulkan 1.1, but only supports loader interface version 4. Interface version 5 or newer required to support this version of Vulkan (Policy #LDP_DRIVER_7)
Warning: loader_scanned_icd_add: Driver /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_intel.so supports Vulkan 1.2, but only supports loader interface version 4. Interface version 5 or newer required to support this version of Vulkan (Policy #LDP_DRIVER_7)
Warning: Layer VK_LAYER_MESA_device_select uses API version 1.2 which is older than the application specified API version of 1.3. May cause issues.
MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
```

---

I also turned off all extensions which didn't help.

Comment: What source and version of chrome are you using?  I believe the latest is snap v118.0.5993.88.  Also, do other browsers work ok?  Chrome is far from the best for a variety of reasons although it is stable and responsive.  You've eliminated a lot of possibilities.  Ubuntu 20.04 is a tad old and I have no way to test your configuration.  Perhaps you're not running the snap version which is what Ubuntu recommends?

Comment: I don't remember how I installed it. It updates on its own (and it just did). It has had this issue for at least a year though (possibly longer) and through many different versions of chrome. I guess I should try uninstalling and reinstalling through snap if that is recommended. Firefox works without any startup hang.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your information and how long this has been going on this could be a backwards compatibility problem with Chrome working with an older *NIX distro. Ubuntu made the shift to supporting Chromium via the snap store ~ when 22.04 was released. I would expect apt versions of Chrome to start exhibiting problems a month or two later. Support for Chromium can be found at https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/

Ubuntu recommends installing apps like this from the snap store. The latest version (11/2/23) is 118.  To see if it's installed.

```
snap list | grep chromium
```

To see if any snaps have updates available:

```
snap refresh --list
```

To install chrome:

```
sudo snap install chromium
```

To update chrome:

```
sudo snap refresh chromium
```

If the snap store isn't installed in your distro:

```
sudo snap install snap-store
```

If you are running an older version of chrome it will show up here:

```
apt list |grep chromium
```

As you noted in your comments, Chromium seems to be lacking some of the features found in Chrome.  Reporting bugs, missing features and obtaining app-specific support for them is beyond the scope of this forum.

I did get sync to work and can import bookmarks and so on but only locally.  There is no link to a login button to a google account at this time.

Your next step might be to contact support to see if they have any insight.  https://support.google.com/chrome/?hl=en-GB&rd=2#topic=7439538

This is the Chromium equivalent to this site although I saw nothing related to your problem there.  There is no Chromium for Ubuntu or even just Linux forum that I could find. I'd suggest making a bug report there just to get the ball rolling.  https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/chromium-discuss

But at least your Chrom[ium] browser is no longer hanging :)

Comment: Is the replacement of chrome with chromium on purpose? There is no similar backwards compatible snap for Chrome for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: I don't know.  I did not deploy the snap version of mozilla or chrome when I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04.  I started having problems not long afterwards.  I installed the snap version of those apps and removed the older stuff and have been problem free ever since.  afaik chromium is the official name of the chrome browser.

Comment: So Chromium doesn't seem to have the freezing issue. Unfortunately I'm not sure it will be usable. It seems it is missing important Chrome features. For example it does not allow me to log in and sync my bookmarks (https://superuser.com/a/1634834/728074, it is especially annoying that they still kept the profile icon and the comment "you are not logged in" while logging in apparently doesn't exists at all anymore.)

(And no Chromium and Chrome are not the same. Chromium is an open source variant related to Chrome but it doesn't have the same features.)

Comment: Google is fundamentally evil so I do not use them any more than absolutely necessary.  I just checked and you are correct, the icon is present but there is no way that I can see to actually log on.  I run Librewolf which is branch of Mozilla Firefox.  Happy my answer fixed the browser freezing problem at least.  There may be a resolution to your log in issue but that is beyond the scope of this forum.  Head over here for more help: https://www.chromium.org/getting-involved/download-chromium/

Comment: Thanks for the try! While this answer "solves" the issue just like suggesting to use Firefox would "solve the issue" I unfortunately don't consider it solved. There is a reason I am trying to use Chrome as I prefer it over others. I'm still hoping someone can think of a solution to keep using chrome. Otherwise I will continue to live with annoying freezes, sigh...

Comment: No worries.  And I completely understand your reasoning.  My guess is that the fix to your issue would need to come from google.  I have not looked into this but there may be a repository that can be added to update Chrome to a better version.  Given the resources needed to do this my guess is that newer versions of Chrome are not backward compatible to older Ubuntu distros and may never be.  Good luck!

Comment: Updated my answer with the contact info for Chrome support.  You'll likely do better there for app support than here.  Best of luck!

Comment: Haha that has never been my experience when contacting software support from big companies. I predict the first reply will be some boilerplate reply that shows they didn't read my message. Than at some point after I point out a dozen times I already tried reinstalling stuff etc, they will say, well you are using an old version of a not so popular OS so you are on your own. It's funny how you can often get much better technical support for software written as a hobby by one developer than by a multi-billion dollar software company.

Comment: The forum I listed in my answer is user based same as here.  So you may find a *NIX guy there who can help.  Definitely file a bug report at the link in my answer.  I can't log in here either although pretty much everything works including sync.  Not clear what features you're missing since you can import and sync in Chromium.  Just that the user accounts are local.  There's no way I can see to log in ala Firefox.  I am running the latest Chromium (118) and a currently supported LTS version of Ubuntu.  Sorry but I'm just not a google guy.

Comment: @ah okay, I guess I can sync with something local (whatever that means, isn't the point to sync with some cloud to have access to the same bookmarks etc at different device). I would have liked to sync with my google account to sync with my other devices.

Comment: Yep, having a profile in the cloud is the whole idea of syncing.  But in the meantime you can import and sync using a local account and access all your google services.  File a bug report and maybe they will fix the login feature.